# How to get the first and last date of previous month without using to_date, trunc and predefined add_months function

Tags: oracle

I wrote the below code but I did not get the expected output:

```
SQL> select TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM')-1,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS PREV_MON_FIRST,
             TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM'),'DD-MM-YYYY')-1 AS PREV_MON_LAST from dual;

select TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM')-1,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS PREV_MON from dual
                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01481: invalid number format model
```

It's correct that 'DD' and 'YYYY' values are missing but when I tried to retrieve only month also it shows the same error

Comment: How can you get any kind of date using the `TO_CHAR` function? That function returns a string, not a date. Forget this nonsense and instead explain the problem you are really trying to solve. `trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - 1` will give you the last date of the previous month, and `trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '1' month` will give you the first date.

Comment: using `to_date` it gives the correct output but i wanted it by `to_char` you are correct at your point it doesn't give date but we can format date using `to_char`

Comment: Which is irrelevant, as you explicitly said that you have to use **only** TO_CHAR (but the mystery remains - why?).

Comment: `select TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mon') AS MON from dual;` if the question was to retrieve month then my query would be valid as for retrieval as above we use to_char

Comment: Regarding the message, did you notice that it says "invalid **number** format model", not "date format not recognized"? It's implicitly treating the string result of the inner `to_char()` as a number - it is not a date at that point.

Comment: yeah that's correct so there's no way we can achieve this without using `to_date, trunc` and predefined `add_months` function.

Comment: What's the charm with these "*without using*" questions? It may be great for amusement ( of the interviewer maybe!),but seems pointless to me as never someone's expected to deliver such a horrible code to production.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja - you don't need to use `to_date()`, you already have a date. You can't do it *only* with `to_char()`, you have to use other functions - date arithmetic combined with `trunc` and `add_months` are enough, and you can even avoid `add_months` by using intervals, as mathguy said originally.

Comment: @AlexPoole agreed thanks !

Comment: Actually i was trying to reach out the query by using different method just for that only i raised this general query its not like some big development application or complex query i asked i just tried reaching the output not with the same exact date format but just a formatted string giving the similar output

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT
    TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -2))) + 1 AS first_date,
    TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1))) AS last_date
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the first day of the previous month using `TO_CHAR` only is easy, if `YYYYMMDD` format suits your needs:

```
SQL> select (to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm') - 1) || '01' first_day
  2  from dual;

FIRST_DAY
------------------------------------------
20180701

SQL>
```

But, for the last day - I have no idea.

---

Usual way to do it *works*, but involves other functions:

```
SQL> select trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'mm') first_day,
  2         trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - 1 last_day
  3  from dual;

FIRST_DAY  LAST_DAY
---------- ----------
2018-07-01 2018-07-31

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Wernfried. Well, it *works*, but produces a wrong result :)  My attempt works in 92% cases, which is quite well, eh? The whole thing is just ... stupid.

Answer (score 0):

For LAST_DAY here is the query with hard_code of values of month without using add_months,trunc,to_date

```
  select to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')||
  to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1||
  case when to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1 in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) THEN 31 
      when to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1 in (4,6,9,11) THEN 30
      when mod(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'),4)=0 and to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1=2 THEN 29
      when mod(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'),4)!=0 and to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1=2 THEN 28
  end 
  from dual
```

Comment: This does not work when the current month is January

Comment: Year 2000 was a leap year! 1900 or 2100 are not.

Comment: Why on earth are you not simply using existing function [LAST_DAY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions072.htm)?

Comment: Thanks Kaushik , Wernfried ... I have modified query to handle leap year and janurary month below :

Answer (score 0):

If I take your question literally one solution is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_LAST_DAY RETURN TIMESTAMP AS
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP;
    return_date_after TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '100' DAY;
BEGIN
    LOOP  
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTHDAY=-1', NULL, return_date_after, next_run_date);
        EXIT WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM next_run_date) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSTIMESTAMP);
        return_date_after := next_run_date;
    END LOOP;    
    RETURN return_date_after;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_FIRST_DAY RETURN TIMESTAMP AS
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP;
    return_date_after TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '100' DAY;
BEGIN
    LOOP  
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTHDAY=1', NULL, return_date_after, next_run_date);
        EXIT WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM next_run_date) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSTIMESTAMP);
        return_date_after := next_run_date;
    END LOOP;    
    RETURN return_date_after;
END;
/
```

It returns the first and last date of previous month without using `TO_DATE` (or `TO_TIMESTAMP`), `TRUNC` or `ADD_MONTHS`

But I hope you agree that your question is rather stupid.

Answer (score 0):

For LAST_DAY here is the query with hard_code of values of month without using add_months,trunc,to_date

select to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')||
  to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1||
  case when to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1 in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) THEN 31 
      when to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1 in (4,6,9,11) THEN 30
      when mod(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'),4)=0 and to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1=2 THEN 29
      when mod(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'),4)!=0 and to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1=2 THEN 28
  end 
  from dual

New Query to handle Janurary and Leap year :

select decode(to_char(sysdate,'mm'),1,to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')-1 ,to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'))||
  decode(to_char(sysdate,'mm'),1,12, to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1)||
  CASE WHEN to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1 in (1,3,5,7,8,10,0) THEN 31 
       WHEN to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1 in (4,6,9,11) THEN 30
       WHEN to_char(sysdate,'mm')-1=2 AND  mod(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'),4)!=0 AND   mod(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'),400)!=0  THEN 29
      ELSE 28
  END 
  FROM dual